# Upload Image to MySQL with nodejs and multer

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, multer

Hello all:  I am working on this node, express, mysql program that needs to upload an image and store its name in MySQL. The image gets uploaded just fine, but I cannot do the insert into MySQL. Sometimes I do not get an error, but the file name is not inserted into the database. Other times, I get the error that filename is undefined.

Here is my index.html:

```
<body>
    This is the webpage
    <p></p>
    <!-- make sure to put enctype="multipart/form-data" -->
    <form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload" method="POST" class="upload-form">
        <label>Select file</label><br />
        <input type="file" name="upload" />
        <br />
        <p></p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
 </body>
```

This is my server.js:

```
//setting up an express server.

//load express
const express = require('express');
//load multer
const multer = require('multer');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
// const fs = require('fs');


//mysql stuff
mysql = require('mysql')
bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'pass123!',
  database : 'images_db'
});

connection.connect();
 
global.db = connection;

//endf of mysql stuff
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'images/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
    // cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },  
});

const limits = {
    fileSize : 4000000
}

//fileFilter function controls which files should be uploaded. req = request being made. file = contains file info. cb = callback function to tell multer when we are done filtering the file. send back an error message to the client with cb.
const fileFilter =(req, file, cb) => {
  //if the file is not a jpg, jpeg, or png file, do not upload it multer; reject it.
  if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
      return cb(new Error('File must be of type JPG, JPEG, or PNG and nore more than 2MB in size'))
  }
  //undefined = nothing went wrong; true = that is true, nothing went wrong, accept the upload.
  cb(undefined, true)
}

//set up the multer middleware
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: limits,
    fileFilter: fileFilter
    // filename: filename
  })

// ROUTES
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  });

  //app.use('/image', express.static('./upload')); // shared uploaded folder with users so users can access the profile images though image folder path


//upload image post route: localhost:port/upload
  app.post("/upload",upload.single('upload'), (req, res) => {
 

    // res.send();
    //mysql stuff
    // var sql = "INSERT INTO `file`(`name`, `type`, `size`) VALUES ('" + req.file.filename + "', '"+req.file.mimetype+"', '"+req.file.size+"')";
    var sql = "INSERT INTO `file`(`name`) VALUES ('" + req.file.filename + "')";
 
    var query = db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
       console.log('inserted data');
    });
    message = "Successfully! uploaded";
    //res.render('index',{message: message, status:'success'});
    //end of mysql stuff
     
    res.redirect('./');
   
}), (error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(400).res.send("You have successfully uploaded the file!");
    // res.redirect('/');
}



app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`);
})
```

Comment: The file name never gets stored in the DB? With what files (type, size, name) does the code throw an error, and with what files does it not throw an error and not save the file name into DB?

Comment: Maxim Orlov: That is correct! The file never gets to the database. It does not throw an error. The file gets uploaded, but the name of the file is not stored in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution by replacing this code:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO `file`(`name`) VALUES ('" + req.file.filename + "')";
 
    var query = db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
       console.log('inserted data');
    });
```

with this code (parameterized query):

```
    let sql = "INSERT INTO  image (name) VALUES (?)";

   db.query(sql, [req.file.filename], function(err, result) {
       console.log('inserted 88 data');
      //  console.log("query ", sql2);
    });
```

Now, I can both upload an image to the server and insert the name of that image into a MySQL database. I hope this helps anyone.